# Can I revert to OS X after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: mac, macosx, bootcamp

I want to download Ubuntu to my Mac but I want to make sure that I can get back to OS X whenever I want. I also wonder that if I can switch OSes with something like bootcamp? (for example you can switch to Windows to OS X and back with bootcamp -  does this work the same with Ubuntu?)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have ubuntu installed alongside. Read this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/MacOSX

Comment: I've found tutorial and I tried doing it my mac doesn'T boot up with rEFIT please help me :(